# Python: Import array from file with indexes intact

Tags: python, arrays, fopen

I have a file that I'd like to import into an array but have each entry as an index so I can call each specific one.

File(testing_array.txt):

```
["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

Script:

```
f = open('testing_array.txt').read()
array = [f]
print (array[0])
print (array[1])
```

Output:

```
["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing_array.py", line 4, in <module>
    print (array[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've tried a for loop unsuccessfully to `.insert` each entry for each index. I just started scripting python 3 days ago so I apologize if I'm overlooking something basic. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `eval()`. Do *not* use `eval()` in production code. It's very dangerous and especially for untrusted input like files.

Comment: After `array = [f]` add `array = array[0]` and tell me if that works please

Comment: @LeonZ., that would probably cause `"["` and `'"'` to be output, since those are the first and second characters in the file respectively.

Comment: @Kevin You're probably right, just wanted to make sure he's really got a string within an array, then take it from there

Comment: @LeonZ. How about `type(f)` then?

Comment: @MadPhysicist That would also work of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the json serializer (it's the same syntax for a **list**).

```
import json

my_list = json.loads('["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]')
```

Comment: Jeez that was really easy. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can also remove the square braces and split the line into list.

```
>>> line = '["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]'
>>> line.strip("[]").split(",")
['"zero"', ' "one"', ' "two"', ' "three"', ' "four"', ' "five"']
```